# Update map value in nested struct in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with dates and comments.

```
dob        | comment
---------------------------
1960-12-01 | this is useful
```

And I want a new column with this type:

```
value_type = T.StructType(
    [
       T.StructField("extra",T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType(), True), True),
       T.StructField("date", T.StringType(), True),
       T.StructField("from_date", T.StringType(), True),
       T.StructField("to_date", T.StringType(), True),
       T.StructField("value", T.StringType(), True),
    ]
)
```

I need to:

1. put the df.date into the `date` field of the struct and
2. put the df.comment into the `extra` map of the struct

thanks to blackbishop I figured out how to do the first part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065968/update-field-in-struct-column-pyspark-withfield-does-not-replace/71066070#71066070) - and i tried to use `.withField()` to update the map but it throws an error:

I tried:

```
(df
.withColumn("new_col", 
            F.struct(*[F.lit(None).cast(f.dataType).alias(f.name) 
                       for f in value_type.fields]))
.withColumn("new_col", (F.col("new_col")
                         .withField("date", F.col("dob"))
                         .withField("extra.value", F.col("comment")))))
```

But I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'update_fields(update_fields(new_col, WithField(dob), WithField(dob)).extra, WithField(dob))' due to data type mismatch: struct argument should be struct type, got: map<string,string>;
```

I am confused as per why it would not work with the map inside the struct?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
(df
.withColumn("new_col", 
            F.struct(*[F.lit(None).cast(f.dataType).alias(f.name) 
                       for f in value_type.fields]))
.withColumn("new_col", (F.col("new_col")
                         .withField("date", F.col("dob"))
                         .withField("extra", 
                                    F.create_map(F.lit("my_key"), F.col("comment")))))
```

The problem was that I was not actually passing a map to a map type!